# adding varying variable to fragment shader breaks the render using opengl GLES20 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying ro render a 3d mesh on android, the positions of the vertices are provided like so:

```
        var positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition").also {
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(it)

            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                it, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, vertexBuffer
            )
        }
```

My vertex shader:

```
    uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;
    attribute vec4 vPosition;
    varying vec4 positionOut;
    void main() {
      gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;
      positionOut = vPosition;
    }
```

Fragment shader:

```
    varying vec4 positionOut;
    precision mediump float;
            void main() {
               gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0,1,1);
            }
```

This code works fine on one device (Android 9 on OnePlus device) but it doesn't work on (Android 10 Samsung Galaxy device) and no errors are thrown.

If I remove the line `varying vec4 positionOut;` from the fragment shader the render works.
The question is why only the definition of a varying variable breaks the render? I don't use the variable now but I want to use it in the next step.

Comment: Perhaps you need to set the precision statement before declaring a positionOut variable.

Comment: That didn't help @alex

Comment: `no errors are thrown` - @derhass seems to have spotted the error, but there's another issue that you've failed to detect an error that should be easily detected. [Here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Example/GLSL_Full_Compile_Linking) is some sample code showing how to detect compilation and link errors - not sure it's the exact right dialect of OpenGL, but it should be close enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is invalid as per [the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.00.pdf):

> The fragment language has no default precision qualifier for floating point types. Hence for float, floating
> point vector and matrix variable declarations, either the declaration must include a precision qualifier or
> the default float precision must have been previously declared.

So you either have to declare it as for example `varying mediump ec4 positionOut;`, or you put into some scope of a `precision` statement.